# How can i open port for microsoft outlook

Tags: linux, iptables

I use firewall and configure iptables command to block all torrent port in my firewall with iptables.
When I add these rules, I can't send and receive email with my outlook with my exchange server in my network.

All web servcices are working:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -m multiport --dports 1024:65535 -m iprange --src-range 192.168.1.1-192.168.1.254 -j DROP

iptables -A FORWARD -p udp -m multiport --dports 1024:65535 -m iprange --src-range 192.168.1.1-192.168.1.254 -j DROP
```

I need your helps to open ports on my firewall iptables configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You havent blocked torrent so much as you've blocked everything that might use a random port number.

Unfortunately this includes Exchange's client protocol, according to what little I can find. The most common information I see says port 135 is used for initial contact only (depending on Server version), and further data transfer is assigned to random server ports from there.

Unless you can configure the clients and server to use only a specific protocol like POP or IMAP (losing much Outlook functionality in the process i'm guessing) or use specific ports, you would need to write a rule allowing all traffic to the specific server ip and set it before your drop rules listed here. Opening a port for the app does not appear to be practical when it uses random port numbers.